# ASCII-Encoded values greater than 127 (0x7F) for TIFF files

Tags: c#, encoding, tiff

I'm trying to encode a TIFF file manually. Whenever byte values greater than 0x7F are encoded they should be written to file as follows:

[image: XFF]

However, whenever I try to write the value of a character greater than 0x7F to file with ASCII encoding it's written as "?" (0x3F).

Does anyone know what the encoding for byte value in the shown image is? 
For reference I'm using C#, writing single chars at a time to a .tif file using the StreamWriter class (StreamWriter::Write(wchar_t)).

Comment: Why are you writing characters instead of bytes?

Comment: also are you using C# or C++?  StreamWriter::Write(wchar_t) looks like C++...

Comment: TIFF is a *binary* file. There is no text encoding involved.

Comment: If you use C#, why don't you use the Bitmap class and save directly to TIFF?

Comment: This sounds like an A/B problem.  What are you actually trying to do?  Odds are that writing characters to the stream (no matter how they are encoded) is not going to help you solve the problem.  If you help us understand why you are trying to do this, we can help guide you to the correct solution.

Comment: ASCII *does not* have values above 127. It is very unclear what you are trying to do and why you are talking about 7-bit encoding for binary file.

Comment: I was mentioning ASCII encoding because of how I was viewing the data from a text editor. This can just be restated in terms of the actual byte values instead of how they're interpreted in text.

To restate the problem statement: all bytes greater than 127 were being written as 63, or other incorrect values depending on the encoding, using the StreamWriter class.

Conclusion: BinaryWriter exists, use it when writing to binary files instead of StreamWriter.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: using the BinaryWriter class instead of StreamWriter allows for encoding of values above 127 as shown in the problem statement.

Going to leave this up as I wasn't able to find this solution through Google using the keywords I mentioned.

I stated I needed ASCII encoding despite the necessity to encode values above 127 (which ASCII doesn't support) because all values below 127 were still given ASCII representation. I didn't know what encoding was needed, just that it was a superset of ASCII.

Comment: The data is not text so no character encoding makes logical sense. In [.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char(v=vs.110).aspx), [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html), … character and string data types are for text.  You could abuse them for non-text data and find an encoding that works but that would just be confusing.